# How I can make Row Grouping in DataGrid WPF Desktop Application

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I wanna make data grouping like this picture:[image]

http://leeontech.wordpress.com/2010/02/01/summary-row-in-datagrid/

There is a code like `RowHeaderStyle` in WPF Silverlight but I don't get it in desktop datagrid.

```
<dg:DataGrid x:Name="dg">
  <dg:DataGrid.RowGroupHeaderStyles>
    <Style... />
  </dg:DataGrid.RowGroupHeaderStyles>
</dg:DataGrid>
```

It uses silverlight application. I'm still don't know how to do this in desktop datagrid using WPF.

Any resources or way to create this? Help please..

Comment: check the grouping section here: http://wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html#grouping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sugget you use `Extended WPF Toolkit™ Community Edition` which is an opensource has `DataGrid` similar to your description https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/ download it.

https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DataGrid&referringTitle=Home has the sample code for DataGrid

https://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/downloads/get/785038 here is the live example. download and see.